# How to read csv file with comma values in a column using pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, spark-csv

My csv file has column values with a comma in it as shown below.

| Name | subject | studentid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | ["CS","DBMS","Big Data"] | 123 |

When I try to read the csv file using spark. My spark data frame is not displaying the complete value of subject column and

[image: spark dataframe display]

what options should I use while reading csv to read the column values with comma correctly ?

Comment: you need to use different field separator while creating csv

Comment: Please read as text file and post some sample data here